# Converting a list of objects to a list of an object property

Tags: c#, linq

If I've got:

```
List<Abc> 

Abc
{
   int myproperty;
}
```

Is there a simple LINQ query which can be used to create:

```
List<int>
```

where `int` is `myproperty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Select` method:

```
List<Abc> list1;

List<int> list2 = list1.Select(x=>x.myproperty).ToList();
```

(of course myproperty should be public)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Abc> varName;
List<int> newList = varName.Select(x => x.myproperty).ToList();
```